# Bootstrap 4: cards as grid with the same height and width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to order cards in a grid with the same height and width. These cards will have different content with different sizes. They should also go by 3 in each row. It is OK for each row to have different height, but the height should be the same within the row. The width of each card should be the same for the whole grid.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-stretch justify-content-start card-deck">
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-text">
        Card 1
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-text">
        Card 1 sasddddddddddddddddd asdd as dassssssssssssssssssssssssss
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-text">
        Card 1
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="w-100">

   </div>
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-text">
        Card 1
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-text">
        Card 1
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9gp76kL/

The result layout I'd like to receive:
[image]

I see issues with current fiddle:

- There is no space between the rows
- The cards have different width for each row

So `card-deck` seems to not enough to do the trick. Is there any easy way around?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply define the width of a card (`style="width: 18rem;"` in the example below) and then use the `col-auto` class for the columns plus the something like `mb-3` (margin-bottom 3 units) for a margin at the bottom. That's it.

And if you wanted to center-align them neatly, you could add the `justify-content-center` to the row. Or maybe try the `justify-content-between` class if you like that better.

### Edit:

I'm adding a second version further down below...

Here's a working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto mb-3">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Second version:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/abc" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card <br> with <br> supporting <br> text below <br> as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/bca" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/bb4" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This <br> card <br> has <br> even longer <br> content <br> than <br> the first <br> to show <br> that equal height action.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/54a" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card <br> with <br> supporting <br> text below <br> as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/f0a" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/aa0" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This <br> card <br> has <br> even longer <br> content <br> than <br> the first <br> to show <br> that equal height action.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/f00" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a longer card <br> with <br> supporting <br> text below <br> as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/090" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4" style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://placehold.it/280x140/ff0" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This <br> card <br> has <br> even longer <br> content <br> than <br> the first <br> to show <br> that equal height action.</p>
                    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't make the cards of the same height. Try to change some of the contents of the card - put a few `<br/>` inside. You will see that the card that has them is higher than the neighbour.

Comment: Just added a *second* version of the code snippet to my answer. Check that out.